# Cutting off the .html from apache readwrite URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have the following rules -

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^oldsite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule   ^(.*)$  https://www.example.com/es/archivo/blog%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

The only issue is that the rewritten URL has a .html at the end, so it looks like 
- `https://www.example.com/es/archivo/blog/......something.html`

How can I get that last .html cut off the end?  I have tried this -

```
RewriteRule   ^(.*)\.html$  https://www.example.com/es/archivo/blog%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

I want the final url to look like

```
https://www.example.com/es/archivo/blog/......something
```

instead of

```
https://www.example.com/es/archivo/blog/......something.html
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use captured value from matching pattern in target like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^oldsite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html$ https://www.example.com/es/archivo/blog/$1 [R=301,L,NC,NE]
```

Clear your browser cache before testing this change.